# how to deploy Comsos Db stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have an Azure Cosmos DB stored procedure and I want it to be included in my Continuous Integration scripts so that it deploys with the solution when the database is deployed.  I'm using VSTS to handle my deployments.  I'm guessing I have to use a powershell script to deploy the stored procedure in the release.  Are there any good examples out there on how to deploy the stored procedures along with the cosmos dbs?

Comment: How do you deploy database through VSTS? You can manage stored procedure through Azure PowerShell: https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#working-with-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more digging, I finally found a good answer.  This [blog post](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/02/20/cosmos-db-server-side-programming-with-typescript-part-6-build-and-deployment/) has all you need to deploy your Cosmos Db stored procedures.